XSLT with two passes so the same input data can support calculations in multiple templates
I am transforming XML into XML using XSLT 1.0. I need to do at least two passes so that I can calculate subtotals on the first pass and use that to output totals in the XML - to appear before the subtotals in the XML structure.
I have the following input XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<invoice>
    <orders>
        <order id="1">
            <lineitem id="1">
                <item quantity="2" price="100"/>
                <item quantity="3" price="50"/>
            </lineitem>
        </order>
        <order id="2">
            <lineitem id="1">
                <item quantity="5" price="20"/>
                <item quantity="1" price="100"/>
            </lineitem>
        </order>
    </orders>
</invoice>

Which I wish to modify by adding in subtotals into the existing element and add a new statistics element at the top:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<invoice>
    <statistics>
        <totalPrice>550</totalPrice>
        <totalQuantity>11</totalQuantity>
    </statistics>
    <orders>
        <order id="1">
            <lineitem id="1">
                <item quantity="2" price="100" subtotal="200"/>
                <item quantity="3" price="50" subtotal="150"/>
            </lineitem>
        </order>
        <order id="2">
            <lineitem id="1">
                <item quantity="5" price="20" subtotal="100"/>
                <item quantity="1" price="100" subtotal="100"/>
            </lineitem>
        </order>
    </orders>
</invoice>

However, I have only got half the solution, where I can add the subtotals, but haven't figured out how to add the statistics element.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><invoice>
    <orders totalPrice="550.00">
        <order id="1">
            <lineitem id="1">
                <item quantity="2" price="100" subtotal="200.00"/>
                <item quantity="3" price="50" subtotal="150.00"/>
            </lineitem>
        </order>
        <order id="2">
            <lineitem id="1">
                <item quantity="5" price="20" subtotal="100.00"/>
                <item quantity="1" price="100" subtotal="100.00"/>
            </lineitem>
        </order>
    </orders>
</invoice>

This is my XSLT so far:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Handling of order items -->
    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:variable name="subtotal" select="@price * @quantity" />
        <item price="{@price}" quantity="{@quantity}" subtotal="{format-number($subtotal,'0.00')}" />
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Root template. Calculates total based on subtotals -->
    <xsl:template match="orders">
        <xsl:variable name="processedOrders">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <orders totalPrice="{format-number(sum(exsl:node-set($processedOrders)//item/@subtotal),'0.00')}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($processedOrders)/*"/>
        </orders>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>

My thinking is that I need to move processedOrders to make it a global variable that I can use in two places:

The orders template (<xsl:template match="orders">) which uses exsl:node-set to sum the sub-totals and get totalPrice.
The new statistics template which will do something similar to output its data.

However, it seems that the way I am making the variable is not working because the orders template is not seeing the data in the variable.
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    Trying to let this be referenced by other templates.
    -->
    <xsl:variable name="processedOrders" select="/invoice/orders"/>
    
    <!-- Handling of order items -->
    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:variable name="subtotal" select="@price * @quantity" />
        <item price="{@price}" quantity="{@quantity}" subtotal="{format-number($subtotal,'0.00')}" />
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Root template. Calculates total based on subtotals -->
    <xsl:template match="orders">
        <orders totalPrice="{format-number(sum(exsl:node-set($processedOrders)//item/@subtotal),'0.00')}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($processedOrders)/*"/>
        </orders>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>

This outputs:
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><invoice>
    <orders totalPrice=\"0.00\">
        <order id=\"1\">
            <lineitem id=\"1\">
                <item quantity=\"2\" price=\"100\"/>
                <item quantity=\"3\" price=\"50\"/>
            </lineitem>
        </order>
        <order id=\"2\">
            <lineitem id=\"1\">
                <item quantity=\"5\" price=\"20\"/>
                <item quantity=\"1\" price=\"100\"/>
            </lineitem>
        </order>
    </orders>
</invoice>


Update: Friday 14 June 2024, 01:36:37 PM
Using @Martin Honnen's answer I was able to get the rest of the way. Martin showed me that I do not need to store the results of the first pass in a global variable, but instead send off the first pass results to the second pass within the same template, and that the second pass can be sent to a root level template - making the second pass go over the whole document again.
The missing piece was how to add the statistics element and not have it duplicated by creating one in the first pass and another in the second pass. I use modes to handle this. Below is my new XSLT stuffed with comments that help me understand what is going on.
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
                extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Two passes.
    The template matching / is the starting point for the transformation.
     
    It's doing two passes over your input by placing the result of the first 
    pass inside a variable and then reprocessing that result in a second pass.
    
    IMPORTANT: we are using modes to discriminate between logic we want to run 
    on the second pass only. 
    - The first pass (first use of <xsl:apply-templates/>
      within this template) has no mode. It will run all other matching templates
      that have no mode.
    - The second pass (second use of <xsl:apply-templates/>) runs in a mode 
      called "add-statistics". This will run all matching templates without a 
      mode plus any templates matching this mode. This is done to ensure that 
      the statistics element is only added once - in the second pass only, and 
      not duplicated within the first pass.
    -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="first-transformation">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($first-transformation)/node()" mode="add-statistics"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Write out the statistics element.
     Will write out the statistics element with the total price and total 
     quantity, but *only* when invoked by a calling template whose mode is
     "add-statistics". This template will be skipped by the first pass, because
     it has no mode. The second pass has the "add-statistics" mode so the 
     element will be added then, ensuring we do not get a duplicate.  
    -->
    <xsl:template match="invoice" mode="add-statistics">
        <invoice>
            <statistics>
                <totalPrice>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(//item/@subtotal),'0.00')"/>
                </totalPrice>
                <totalQuantity>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(//item/@quantity)"/>
                </totalQuantity>
            </statistics>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </invoice>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Handling of order items.
    The template matching item multiplies the price and quantity attributes of 
    each item element to calculate a subtotal, then produces a new item element 
    with the price, quantity and calculated subtotal as attributes.
    -->
    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:variable name="subtotal" select="@price * @quantity"/>
        <item price="{@price}" quantity="{@quantity}" subtotal="{format-number($subtotal,'0.00')}"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Root template. Calculates total based on subtotals
     The template matching orders calculates the total price by summing all the 
     subtotals, then produces a new orders element with that total as one attribute.-->
    <xsl:template match="orders">
        <orders totalPrice="{format-number(sum(//item/@subtotal),'0.00')}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </orders>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Identity template.
     The identity template is a design pattern that is used in XSLT where one
     wants to transform a source tree into a result tree, making changes to some
     part of it but keeping the rest of the tree the same. This basically copies
     over anything that doesn't match another template rule
     -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


Which XSLT 1.0 processor are you using? There are some that can do this in one pass, using EXSLT dynamic extension functions: https://exslt.github.io/dyn/index.html

Am using Xalan J. Just figured that out. Will look at that page, thanks @michael.hor257k.

You need to run to passes on the complete document and in the second pass you can compute the totals; for simplicity I have not used two modes but just a variable and eliminate the wrong/empty totals from the first pass computation by not processing the attribute on orders:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="first-transformation">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($first-transformation)/node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Handling of order items -->
    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:variable name="subtotal" select="@price * @quantity" />
        <item price="{@price}" quantity="{@quantity}" subtotal="{format-number($subtotal,'0.00')}" />
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Root template. Calculates total based on subtotals -->
    <xsl:template match="orders">
        <orders totalPrice="{format-number(sum(//item/@subtotal),'0.00')}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </orders>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>


That gave me the hint I needed to finish the solution. Now I understand better how to implement multiple passes.

If you are using the Xalan-J processor, you can take advantage of the EXSLT dyn:sum() extension function to complete the entire transformation in a single pass:
XSLT 1.0 + EXSLT
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
extension-element-prefixes="dyn">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/invoice">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- add grand totals -->
        <xsl:variable name="items" select="orders/order/lineitem/item"/>
        <statistics>
            <totalPrice>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(dyn:sum($items, '@quantity * @price'), '0.00')"/>
            </totalPrice>
            <totalQuantity>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum($items/@quantity)"/>
            </totalQuantity>
        </statistics>
        <!-- process orders --> 
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <!-- add subtotal -->
    <item quantity="{@quantity}" price="{@price}" subtotal="{format-number(@quantity * @price, '0.00')}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Although a purist would point out that this method has a flaw of calculating the subtotals twice.

Needed to adjust the item template like so: <xsl:template match="item"> <item quantity="{@quantity}" price="{@price}"> <xsl:attribute name="subtotal"> <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@quantity * @price, '0.00')"/> </xsl:attribute> </item> </xsl:template>

That's brilliant! I didn't think Xalan Java 2.7.2 supported the dynamic tag. I am not concerned with calculating those totals twice, though I normally would be. This is an example I concocted to help me with my real issue. Needed to figure out how to use this tech better. Thank you.

There is no need for the adjustment; I just forgot the curly braces in the original post (you must have missed the edit). My answer to the purist is sure, but compare the total amount of processing of the two methods.
